# Running Command line commands within Java

Tags: java, command-line

Is it possible to run this cmd line command `curl ipinfo.io` within java?

I want to then pull the lat and long or "loc" from it afterwards.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
var p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("curl ipinfo.io")
```

And read the output like:

```
  try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
                return bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace()
            }
```

Comment: this is the way I do it too

Comment: FWIW, executing external commands in java is usually an anti-pattern. There are plenty of libraries which can do HTTP transfers in Java.

Comment: @GyroGearless you mean for HTTP? That I can agree with. Not every external command is an anti-pattern.